# Space before section titles with twocolumns and sections that cross both columns

Tags: sectioning, two-column

I'm writing a document in twocolumn mode, but I am starting pages with sections with some long titles that I'm trying to spread over both columns.  The vertical space before subsequent section titles seems to be reduced compared to normal.

The following example illustrates what is happening.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[\section{A very very very very very long title}]

The paragraph is then followed by somewhat reduced space before:

\subsection{The subsection}

aaaa

\end{document}
```

(Compare with the vertical space before the `\subsection` if I replace the line beginning `\twocolumn` with a simple `\section{Short title}`.)

What is the correct way to attempt to do what I'm doing?  I wasn't sure whether the `multicol` package would help - since I wanted the twocolumn setup to cover the whole document, it didn't quite feel right structurally to have twocolumn environments sprinkled liberally throughout the document.

(Finally, I'm using (pdf)LaTeX, so please no LuaLaTeX or XeTeX answers please! :-) )

Comment: Each `\twocolumn` command starts a new page; are you sure you want it?

Comment: The extra-wide section title will only occur at the top of a page, so in this case, yes I think I do want a new page.  (In my real example, I've got a different command instead of the `\twocolumn[\section{...}]` bit, but the above is a minimal example illustrating my issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\twocolumn` is not supposed to work like this. However, the problem is that `\if@nobreak` is not reset correctly. Add it explicitly.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetnobreak{\@nobreakfalse}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[\section{A very very very very very long title}\resetnobreak]

The space after this paragraph will be regular. \lipsum[2]

\subsection{The subsection}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fix.  That works nicely.  By "`\twocolumn` is not supposed to work like this", do you mean that this is a bug?  Or that I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: @MartynQuick Neither. ;-) I'd call it "a feature". Possibly `\if@nobreak` should be reset to false, but this might break in presence of pending two column floats.